# Implicit interfaces for type returned from a type

Tags: go

I want to decouple my packages. Go proverbs say "Accept interfaces, return structs". I can accept a bookInterface containing a title which I have defined in package B so as to not reference package A containing the type. However if that book contains Page structs which have a title I cannot define an interface for that page and use PageInterface in bookInterface... So implicit interfaces only work for depth 1 or is this different?

```
./prog.go:54:11: cannot use book (type *Book) as type BookInterface in argument to PrintBook:
    *Book does not implement BookInterface (wrong type for Pages method)
        have Pages() []Page
        want Pages() []PageInterface
```

Sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Book struct {
   title string

   pages []Page
}


func (b *Book) Title() string {
    return b.title;
}

func (b *Book) Pages() []Page{
    return b.pages;
}

type Page struct {
   title string
}

func (p *Page) Title() string {
    return p.title;
}

type BookInterface interface {
 Title() string 

 Pages() []PageInterface 
}

type PageInterface interface {
   Title() string 
}

func PrintBook(book BookInterface ) {
    fmt.Println(book.Title());
    fmt.Println(book.Pages()[0].Title());
}


func main() {

    book := &Book{title: "my title", pages: []Page{Page{title: "my page title"}}}

    fmt.Println(book.Title());
    fmt.Println(book.Pages()[0].Title());
    
    
    PrintBook(book);
}
```

I don't want this package to directly link to package A. Is that possible with this kind of data structure? Is what I'm trying to do, stupid? What are my options?

https://play.golang.org/p/zH9dzfF5ocB

Comment: @mkopriva even if ```(b *Book) Pages() []Page``` returns an interface it won't work... even if both package A and package B have identical interfaces... seems to only work for top level type.

Comment: my bad, the first comment linked something that's not really related to your problem. The problem you're having is that `[]Page` and `[]PageInterface` are two different types (regardless of the fact that the element type of one implements the element type of the other). Therefore, also, the two signatures `Pages() []Page` and `Page() []PageInterface` are completely different, and here you can disregard the "level", e.g. `Page() Page` and `Page() PageInterface` are also completely different signatures. Lastly, to satisfy an interface, the signatures *must match verbatim*.

Comment: Pure duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You're not implementing the interface correctly. You've clearly defined the signature of `Pages` in the interface as returning `[]PageInterface`. Yet, your implementation returns `[]Page`. A `Page` may implement `PageInterface`, but `[]Page` does not implement `[]PageInterface` (because there is nothing to implement - it's a *slice of interfaces*, **not** an interface). You'll need to update the signature of `Book`. Here's one way you can accomplish it:

```
func (b *Book) Pages() []PageInterface {
    pages := make([]PageInterface, len(b.Pages))
    for i, p := range b.Pages {
        pages[i] = p
    }
    return pages;
}
```

Comment: ```PageInterface``` would be part of package B. I want to consume package A without directly depending on package A via an interface but it seems that the interface must use the struct/interface types of the provider package.

Comment: Yes, as already mentioned in the comments, the signatures must match *verbatim*, which includes package prefixes. It sounds like you haven't chosen the correct boundaries for your packages. Maybe your package B (or parts of it) belong in package A instead. It seems like you are fighting your own design.